# Beaglebone Black Rev C Debian Wheezy doesn't work with ROS?

Tags: ros, debian, wheezy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ROS ready for Debian on the BBB Rev C? Looks like there are many unavailable packages still. ROScore would not run or couldn't be found. The step: "Install bootstrap dependencies" failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169276/beaglebone-black-rev-c-debian-wheezy-doesn%27t-work-with-ros?/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2014-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
Which installation instructions are you following? There are lots of debs available for Ubuntu on BBB; is installing Ubuntu an option for you?

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2014-05-26**:
I must have made a mistake with some command. Today it is working flawlessly for Debian. It surely takes a while to prepare the environment on the wstool init command. That little BBB CPU is hot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is working fine but now I've filled up the 4 Gig eMMC with Debian and ROS. There must be a way to instruct it to install other files in the Micro SD. How does one do that? Actually I wouldn't need Gazebo and the Laser modules since I'm not planning on using them. The Micro SD is 16 Gig, so it should have plenty of room. Clearly ROS is "a piece of work!"

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tsounix](https://answers.ros.org/users/21029/tsounix/) on 2014-12-04**:
How did you overcome the error? :
python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.